# WooCommerce has_term stopped working after updating to WordPress 6.0

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements

I have several conditionals for different WooCommerce categories where I use `has_term` to check the category. After updating to WordPress 6.0 it stopped working.

How can I debug this? Is there an alternative to `has_term`? The `debug.log` shows nothing wrong.

Here's an example of my code:

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_columns', 'lw_loop_shop_columns' );
function lw_loop_shop_columns( $columns ) {
    if ( !is_shop() && has_term( array ( 'cursos', 'courses', 'talleres', 'workshops', 'safaris-fotograficos', 'photo-safaris', 'turismo-alternativo', 'alternative-tourism', 'servicios', 'services', 'software', 'software-en', 'aventuras-fotograficas', 'photo-adventures' ), 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $columns = 2;
    } else {
        $columns = 3;
    }
    return $columns;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was related to a bad upgrade.

I fixed it by rolling back to a previous WordPress version using [WP Downgrade](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-downgrade/), then I upgraded again from `wp-admin/update-core.php`.